# How to stop WebApi project from Owin WebApp

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I have a WebApi called MyWebApi project that run on port 42000 in debug mode.
I created a console application with Owin to host MyWebApi using the following technique:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {            
    using (WebApp.Start<WebApi.Startup>("http://localhost:9000/"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server is running...");
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter key to stop it.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Server is shutting down...");
}
```

Everything work fine. I can get and post data from both ports 9000 and 42000.
After I stop my console, I still can post and get data from port 42000. 
Are there any way to stop the MyWebApi just like we stop debugging directly from WepApi project?

thanks,

Austin

Answer (score 1):

Try disposing your webApp:

```
 using (var _webApp=WebApp.Start<WebApi.Startup>("http://localhost:9000/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server is running...");
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter key to stop it.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    _webApp.Dispose();// Add this
}

Console.WriteLine("Server is shutting down...");
```

Comment: I have tried to dispose the WebApp manually and the WebApi on port 42000 still running.  The dispose method stop the Server which runs on port 9000 only.

Comment: But when you host this web app,is it taking both ports? I don't see how. Are you sure that is not an old app that you run earlier using port 42000?

Comment: Just clarify : 
The console host app has no other codes than the main method that host the existing WebApi. After starting  the console app, I can talk to both ports:                                                                                                             

http://localhost:9000/api/users/get/5  ==> Valid
http://localhost:42000/api/users/get/5 ==> Valid


After turn off the console
http://localhost:9000/api/users/get/5  ==> Invalid
http://localhost:42000/api/users/get/5 ==> Valid

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly IUnityContainer _container = UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer();

        public static void StartServer()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8081/";
            var startup = _container.Resolve<Startup>();
            IDisposable webApplication = WebApp.Start(baseAddress, startup.Configuration);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started...");

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            finally
            {
                webApplication.Dispose();
            }
        }        
    }
```

[SELF HOST WEBAPI WITH OWIN AND UNITY](https://damienbod.com/2013/10/01/self-host-webapi-with-owin-and-unity/)

**webApplication.Dispose();** - stop webapi server

Comment: Using statement will dispose the WebApp once user press any key. In this case, the only server that is  listening on port 9000 will be disposed. The actual WebApi which is listing on port 42000 still running.